# C# Write Resource from Download

Tags: c#, resources, download

Alright, so I have been wondering how to do this for a while. Basically, what I want to do is instead of downloading a file directly to the hard drive can I make my application "download it to resources"

I need to Download the file or bytes, and write it to resources.

Using a method like this to download

```
        byte[] example;
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            example = client.DownloadData("http://example.com/file.exe");
        }
```

If this is not possible

Would I be able to download my program into bytes then run it. All of these programs are .NET assemblies.

Comment: What do you mean by "download it to resources"?

Comment: @Kangkan Exactly why I used quotes. Basically, I want to write something to resources. That my client has to download.

Comment: This is not what resources are intended for. Please describe your initial problem, then we'll be able to give you some advice on how to solve it.

Comment: @Fyodor Soikin My problem is I want my client to run my other programs from memory. Basically making a secure login client for my programs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I'm kinda understanding what you want to do, your question was not clearly stated and confused everybody. So you wanna run a program which is downloaded from the Internet right? And you don't want to store that program on the hard disk but to load it to the memory on-the-fly, do you? In that case, check out:

[How can I launch a program from memory in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595504/how-can-i-launch-a-program-from-memory-in-c)

and

http://blog.devexperience.net/en/9/Load_an_EXE_file_and_run_it_from_memory.aspx

Comment: Yes, this is what I would like to do. :) I will take a look at those.

Answer (score 1):

Resource files are meant to act as static data repositories. If you want this sort of functionality, I suggest you use an embedded database such as [SQLite](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/) or [SQL Server Compact Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/compact.aspx).